# Schedule Knime Workflow

Tags: sql-server, windows, workflow, schedule, knime

I need to schedule Knime Workflow to run daily as I wasn't able to understand/put together the steps in (knime.com/faq#q12) due to my business background. My environment details are:

- Operating System: Windows Server 2012 R2.
- Database: Reading from SQL Server 2017 and insert model output to the same 
  database.
- Knime Version: Analytical Platform 3.5.2
- The Knime Analytical Platform is installed on D drive.
- The Workflow is saved on E drive.

could you share with me in details the needed process as I'm coming from a business background :

- The needed batch file with exact commands.
- Other need steps to run it daily

Comment: That's nice. Let us know when you are done or encounter problems during your implementation. SO is not a free code-writing service. As stated, your question is far too broad and likely to be closed. I suggest you review the information about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you James for your comment and sorry if my question is broad ... As I mentioned I come from a business background, and I need to implement this due to urgent business requirements ... to be more specific I would appreciate any info to generate the batch file as I wasn't able to understand/put together the steps in (https://www.knime.com/faq#q12) - @SMor

Answer (score 2):

I use the following command on Windows systems to run an exported workflow as a scheduled task.

You must use quotes around the path of your workflow and path to your Knime executable.

```
"/path/to/knime.exe" -reset -nosave -nosplash -application org.knime.product.KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION -workflowFile="/path/to/workflowFile"
```